# Anharmonic terms of Lagrangian of spring pendulum with free support

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring

I am trying to find the normal modes of a spring pendulum with moving support. The spring has spring constant $k$ and unstretched length $l_0$.

[image]

Sorry for my bad paint skills. The problem was stated to have three degrees of freedom. Let $x$ described the distance of the block of mass $M$ from equilibrium. Let the length of the pendulum be described by $l = l_0 + r$. Lastly $\theta$ is the angle of oscillation. Then the kinetic energy is,
\begin{equation}
T = \frac{1}{2}M\dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2+(l_0+r)^2\dot{\theta}^2)
\end{equation}
The potential energy is then,
\begin{equation}
V = \frac{1}{2}kr^2 - mg(l_0+r)cos(\theta)
\end{equation}
So the Lagrangian is,
\begin{equation}
L = \frac{1}{2}M\dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2+(l_0+r)^2\dot{\theta}^2) - \frac{1}{2}kr^2 + mg(l_0+r)cos(\theta)
\end{equation}
In small angle approximation we have,
\begin{equation}
L = \frac{1}{2}M\dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2+(l_0+r)^2\dot{\theta}^2) - \frac{1}{2}kr^2 + mg(l_0+r) - \frac{1}{2}mg(1_0+r)\theta^2
\end{equation}
The problem says to ignore anharmonic terms but I am a bit confused as to which terms that would be. I think that the anharmonic terms would be $mgr\theta^2$ but I am confused whether or not $(l_0+r)^2\dot{\theta}^2$ is anharmonic.

So if I follow my gut then I eliminate $mgr$ and $-\frac{1}{2}mgr\theta^2$ and the kinetic energy matrix is then
\begin{pmatrix}
M & 0 & 0\\
0 & m & 0 \\
0 & 0 & m(l_0+r)^2
\end{pmatrix}
and then potential
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & k & 0 \\
0 & 0 & mgl_0
\end{pmatrix}
But I'm not sure if the $m(l_0+r)^2$ term belongs in the matrix. I feel like it should be $ml_0^2$ but I am not sure.

Also I am not 100% sure that I got the Lagrangian correct so please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to keep track of this is to write $\ell=\ell_0+\epsilon r$ and use $\epsilon \theta$ rather than $\theta$.  Expanding your Lagrangian in powers of $\epsilon$, you can then use $\epsilon$ as a counter to keep track of "smallness".  The anharmonic terms are those with 3 or more powers of $\epsilon$ in the Lagrangian, or two or more powers of $\epsilon$ in the equations of motion.

Comment: would that mean $\dot{r} = \dot{\epsilon}r + \dot{r}\epsilon$, or $\dot{r} =\epsilon \dot{r}$?

Comment: @JosephSanders $\epsilon$ is constant.  It's just a dummy constant to keep track of the degree of each term when you expand in powers of $\epsilon$.  Quadratic terms will be those of degree $\epsilon^2$ etc.

Comment: okay that makes sense, thank you!